# How to set background of a view (UITableview) with dynamic cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, background

I am trying to set a background Colour to the view occupied by the UITableViewCell. I have dragged an outlet and have a gradient layer which i return to it

```
extension CAGradientLayer{
func viewGradient(topColour:UIColor,bottomColour : UIColor) -> CAGradientLayer{
   let gradientColor: [CGColor] = [topColour.cgColor, bottomColour.cgColor]
   let gradientLocations: [Float] = [0.0/1.0]
   let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
   gradientLayer.colors = gradientColor
   gradientLayer.locations = gradientLocations as [NSNumber]?

   return gradientLayer
  }
}
```

And i access this method in my `viewDidLoad` method of a view controller

```
 let bottomColour = UIColor(red: (0.018), green: (0.38), blue: (0.64), alpha: 1.0)
 let topColour = UIColor(red: (0.13), green: (0.63), blue: (0.67), alpha: 0.7)
 let background = CAGradientLayer().viewGradient(topColour:topColour,bottomColour : bottomColour)
 background.frame = self.view.bounds
 self.view.layer.insertSublayer(background, at: 0)
 myMenu.layer.insertSublayer(background, at: 0)
```

I have dynamic cells in my table view and as the number of cells increases the view slides down and i Have to scroll to see my cells.I have white spaces. Is there any way i can set the entire scrolling region to have my background gradient colour or am i missing something ?

[Here is the screenshot of the images showing my exact problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylS9m.jpg)

Comment: `UITableView` has a `backgroundView` property for putting a fixed view behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented above, `UITableView` has a `backgroundView` property.

In your `viewDidLoad` method, keep your `background` constant declared as is, then below add:

`self.tableView.backgroundView = background`

Hope that helps.